# ChipGroup chip index out of bounds

Tags: android

I have a ChipGroup comprised of category names. When I leave the fragment and come back to it, the index increases. So the first chip goes from index 1 to 11, causing an index out of bounds exception. The count of the chips is always correct, so I'm not sure how the index is increasing. I've attempted to clear the views if the count is greater than zero.

```
 // onViewCreated
            @Override
        public void onCheckedChanged(ChipGroup chipGroup, int i) {
            Log.d(TAG, String.valueOf(i).concat(" : index of chip"));
            binding.categorySearchbar.setText("");
            if (i != -1) {
                index = i;
                if (categoriesList != null) {
                    if (i == 1) {
                        viewModel.searchByCategoryId(categoriesList.get(i - 1).getCategoryId());
                        binding.chipgroup.setSingleLine(true);
                        binding.selectedCategory.setText(categoriesList.get(i - 1).getName());
                        binding.selectedCategory.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                    } else {
                        viewModel.searchByCategoryId(categoriesList.get(1).getSubcategory().get(i - 2).getCategoryId());
                        binding.chipgroup.setSingleLine(true);
                        binding.selectedCategory.setText(categoriesList.get(1).getSubcategory().get(i - 2).getName());
                        binding.selectedCategory.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                    }
                }
            } else {
                binding.chipgroup.setSingleLine(false);
                adapter.clearList();
                binding.selectedCategory.setVisibility(View.GONE);
            }
        }
    });

//setting the chips
    private void setCategories(List<Category> categories) {
    if (getContext() != null) {
        if (binding.chipgroup.getChildCount() > 0) {
            binding.chipgroup.removeAllViewsInLayout();
            binding.chipgroup.removeAllViews();
        }

        for (Category cat : categories) {
            if (!cat.getName().equals("Shop by Category")) {
                Chip chip = new Chip(getContext());
                chip.setText(cat.getName());
                chip.setCheckable(true);
                chip.setClickable(true);
                binding.chipgroup.addView(chip);
            } else {
                for (Subcategory sub : cat.getSubcategory()) {
                    Chip chip = new Chip(getContext());
                    chip.setText(sub.getName());
                    chip.setCheckable(true);
                    chip.setClickable(true);
                    binding.chipgroup.addView(chip);
                }
            }
        }
    }
    Log.d(TAG, "setCategories : ".concat(String.valueOf(binding.chipgroup.getChildCount())));
}
```

Answer (score 0):

So the value of `int i` in `public void onCheckedChanged(ChipGroup chipGroup, int i)` is not actually an index. It is an id rather. I was under the impression that is an index but it is not. My overall solution was to set a click listener to each chip when it was declared and handle the logic in there.

https://developer.android.com/reference/com/google/android/material/chip/ChipGroup.OnCheckedChangeListener.html#onCheckedChanged(com.google.android.material.chip.ChipGroup,%20int)